# Localhost:3000 claims "gem 'pg'" in not installed, Heroku app is working fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

My `localhost:3000` is giving me this error:

> Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

The gem is installed and has been bundled. What confuses me is that the Heroku app is working fine. I also get the same error when I try to run `rake db:create`.

I'm currently enrolled in a course learning RoR, I have asked this question in the community forums, but no luck.

My gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'


gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do

gem 'pg', '~>0.18.3'

gem 'rails_12factor'

end

group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'

end

group :development do

  gem 'spring'

end
```

My database.yml is:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:

  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_development
  username: davideye
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
  port: 5432


test:

  <<: *default
  database: my_test
  username: davideye
  password: 1234

production:

  <<: *default
  database: my_production
  username: davideye
  password: 1234
```

Comment: show your gemfile. I think it's the problem of where you have put the pg gem. You need to add `pg`  in `production` environment and whatever  else you are using in dev in `development` env

Comment: gem pg is in production and sqlite3 is in development. Stackflow won't let me post a screenshot, as I am a new user

Comment: Just copy paste the `gemfile` as code in your question. You don't need the screenshoot.

Comment: Could you please post the contents for your database.yml 
Please make sure that you defined `sqlite` adapter for development.

Comment: As @Dusht said can you now post the contents of your database.yml

Comment: I did. Formatting is messed up. First time asking a question here so I'm still figuring stuff out.

Comment: @Eyelabs: have you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: Looks like @nik is right. You have the pg gem only in the production group.

Comment: @GaganGami no change

Comment: In database.yml you have defined `postgres` for development where as in gemfile you have defined `sqlite3`.

Comment: Thanks @nik that fixed it! It all makes sense now! Thanks everyone who contributed, and for making my first question successful!

Comment: No issues just remember to put all the related code in proper format whenever you ask a question. Please format your question properly. Giving 4 spaces on each line when the line contains code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In database.yml you have defined `postgres` for development where as in gemfile you have defined `sqlite3` for development. So either change your database.yml or in gemfile in development instead of `sqlite3` write `pg`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with your Gemfile.

```
    group :production do
      gem 'pg', '~>0.18.3'
      gem 'rails_12factor'
    end
```

This tells Bundler to only load `pg` in production (which is why it works on Heroku).

You could either move `gem 'pg' ...` out of the `group :production` block so that it's included in development too, or use sqlite3 in your dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `sqlite3` for both `dev` and `test` env

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Change adapter to `sqlite3` in your development and test block as well.

```
# config/database.yml
default: &default
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/my_development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/my_test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_production
  username: davideye
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you added gem 'pg' in production mode & for development you are using 'sqlite' as per your gemfile but you are using postgresql for development according to your database.yml

So , remove gem 'pg' from production block & put it before any block.